# Interpret the effect of factor in GAMM

Tags: r, data-visualization, mgcv

this will probably look like a trivial question but I am having trouble explaining the difference between the output plots of two models I built.

My data are disease counts on algae. I would like to test the relationship between disease counts and percentage cover (continuous covariable) including the effect of Site (fixed categorical) and Zone (random, nested within Site).

```
mod1<-gamm(Nblesions~s(Cover),random =list(Site=~1,Zone=~1),family=poisson,data=df)
```

with the resulting plot:
[image]

```
mod2<-gamm(NbLesions~s(Cover)+Site,random=list(Site=~1,Zone=~1),
family=poisson,data=df)
```

with the resulting plot:
[image]

The difference between the two models is the absence of factor Site in mod2. In both models there is NO significant effect of cover.

Could anyone explain to me what is happening between the two and how to interpret the change in the relationship when Site is added?

Any advice would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: These are partial plots, so they show the effect of Cover whilst holding the other variables at their mean or baseline level. `gamm()` is doing (RE)ML smoothness selection for you as the smoothness penalties are part of the random effects of the model; hence once Site is accounted for, the optimal model according to the (RE)ML criterion is to shrink the smooth function for cover to a linear function using 1 df. I suspect that there is a "Site" effect in the first plot that confounds with Cover, hence a more complex fit seems to do better initially.

Comment: Hi Gavin-Thanks for the explanation. mod2 is then a better model than mod1. Regarding the random factor Zone nested within Site, would you say random=list(Site=~1,Zone=~1) was the right way to incorporate it? I was not so sure about it.

Comment: You have shown no evidence for me to decide which is a better model. You can look at the AIC/BIC of the models, & look at the residuals; plot them by Site to see if there is a Site effect. (I only suggested one way in which you might get the above plot differences.) I'm not sure about the random effect specification; I *think* you have it right but I don't use that list form often enough to be sure. You might consider the **gamm4** package, also by Simon Wood, which uses the lme4 pkg (instead of nlme) to fit the GAMM & which has easier ways to specify the random effects terms.

Comment: @Gavi Simpson-Thanks a lot for the input. I thought we could consider mod2 as a better model since it accounts for the factor Site (knowing that there is a significant Site effect) whereas the other does not. I will look into all your suggestions carefully.